# Matching and removing an item from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, regex

I really have no idea why I'm struggling with this so much. I'm scraping video ID's from YouTube into an ArrayList and I need to remove a couple. I have tried several different ways to remove this yet none of them work.

This is what I have

```
while (m.find()) {
   if (m.group(0) == "default.jpg")
      //Do nothing
   } else { 
      allMatches.add(m.group(0));
      count++;
   }
}
```

Then I try

```
int i = 0;
while (i < allMatches.size()) {
   if (allMatches.get(i) == "default.jpg") {
      allMatches.remove()
   }
   i++;
}
```

Also doesn't work. And finally, when setting an image I try this

```
if (allMatches.get(position).toString() == "default.jpg") {
   allMatches.remove(position);                 
   bitmap = null;
}
```

Why are none of these working? default.jpg is definitely being picked up as it isn't being removed from the gridview.

Alternatively, if anyone knows how to do stop the following expression from picking up 'default.jpg' and 'video?view' then I'd love to hear your suggestions.

```
String expr = "(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11}(?=&)|
   (?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]{11}|(?<=v=)[^&\n]{11}";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.equals`

```
 if (allMatches.get(position).toString().equals("default.jpg")) {
    }
```

May be it works and if dont,,post your `allMatches` list array with `element....`

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in comparing strings in java. Strings in java are objects. They are not to be compared with the `==` operator. Use the equals method:

```
str1.equals(str2)
```

In your case:

```
"default.jpg".equals(allMatches.get(i))
```

When you compare strings using `==` method you actually compare the references and not the values.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot compare strings in java with "==" you must use `string.equals("stringtomatch")`

Just to clarify the "==" on a string is comparing memory addresses not the actual string value. So you can use "==" but it won't result in the value you are expecting.